# Codificação / Acentos / Pontuação / Símbolos R Markdown foram embora

Tags: r, codificação-de-caracteres, rmarkdown

Tenho tido uma situação altamente chata e os tutoriais anteriores não ajudaram. Mudei recentemente de computador e agora, os acentos do R Markdown simplesmente se perderam. Uso windows 10 e o arquivo da imagem abaixo é a sintaxe do R Markdown.

`exploratória` virou `explorat?ria`

`possível` virou `poss?vel`

`porção` virou `por??o`

[image: Codificação]
[image: Codificacao animada]

Vezes anteriores, havia conseguido reverter isso digitando no Console

```
Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")
```

Save with encoding não funciona.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2 tools_3.5.2    yaml_2.2.0
```

Comment: Tente "Re-open with the enconding" ao invés de "save with encoding". E só depois que deu certo, "save with encoding".
Mas detalhe, se o seu arquivo já foi salvo uma vez sem ter sido aberto corretamente, não é garantia que o mesmo funcione. Se isso funcionar, eu elaboro a resposta melhor, agora não posso. aguardo feedback

Comment: Obrigado, @GuilhermeParreira. O re-open infelizmente não funcionou para reverter a codificação.

Comment: Vixe, a não ser que o arquivo tenha sido corrompido. Qual era o sistema operacional do seu computador antigo?

Comment: Oi, @GuilhermeParreira. Ambos era o windows 10. Estou aqui tentando resolver também e se conseguir, dou o feedback. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada!! Disponibilize o arquivo aqui, ou parte dele pelo menos, se possível

Comment: Você já tentou mudar o "Re-open with the enconding" para ISO-8859 e depois "Re-open with the enconding" para "utf-8" de novo? Funcionou para mim.

Answer (score 0):

é mais simples que isso, se você colocar o teclado em: `en ou en-us` ele não vai deixar você usar o acento, e algumas teclas iram deixar de funcionar, faça o seguinte caminho:

menu inicial >> configurações >> hora e idioma

1° altere a região para português do brasil

2° você vai altera na aba idioma(clicando em cima de cada um):

- tela do windows
- apps e sites
- formato de região e
- fala

para português(brasil)

No teclado você vai alterar para **Português do Brasil ABTN2** e depois **marca as duas caixas que estão logo abaixo**.

pronto, depois disso deve funcionar normalmente.

- se algum aplicativo ainda não estiver funcionando, você digita windows update no menu inicial e verifica se possui atualizações, após, reinicie o computador.

se não funcionar, volte a postar, podemos tentar reinstalar os aplicativos nativos.